# WildFly - How to get the main configured JSF version with "jboss-cli"?

Tags: jsf, jboss, wildfly, jboss-cli

I would like to get the main configured JSF version but

`[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=jsf:list-active-jsf-impls`

leads only to

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => ["main"]
}
```

Moreover no solution with

`[standalone@localhost:9990 /] /subsystem=jsf:read-attribute(name=default-jsf-impl-slot)`

```
{
    "outcome" => "success",
    "result" => "main"
}
```

When I run wildfly the output is

`09:35:41,830 INFO  [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.config] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 78) Mojarra 2.3.14.SP01...`

But how to get this version with `jboss-cli`?

Have I overlooked something in https://docs.wildfly.org/21/Admin_Guide.html#JSF?

WildFly 21.0.0.Final

Comment: I don't believe this is possible with CLI.